# bash export function for other script non interactive

Tags: bash

I have a bash file with a list of functions.
If I add to other script the header:

```
source /myusefulfuncionlist.sh
```

they can call the functions inside the file.

Is there a way to avoid this add to keep it DRY?
If I add to /etc/bash.bashrc I can access function from user shell but scripts won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [bash manual startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> Invoked non-interactively
>
> When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute. ...

Edit `/etc/environment` and add:

```
BASH_ENV=/fullpathto/myusefulfuncionlist.sh
```

**and relogin** and non-interactive shells should pick up your source file.